# Two buttons interfering?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm working on a webpage but i'm a designer not a developer, I have a problem with my buttons. Here's the code`

```
<style>
#chat {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#000;
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
    display:block;
    z-index:99999;
}
#chatbtn {
    background:#666;
    width:310px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:14;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    background:#333;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#chatbtn h3 {
    background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-5px -574.5px;
    margin:0;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:40px;
    line-height:2.2;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:700;
}
#box {
    position:relative;
    width:890px;
    height:100px;
    top:130px;
    z-index:14;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#box .left_part {
    width:810px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
#box .left_part .top {
    width:790px;
    height:54px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#box .left_part .bottom {
    width:810px;
    height:45px;
}
#box .right_part {
    width:80px;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
}
.media_icons {
    width:190px;
    height:45px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.song_titel {
    width:510px;
    height:45px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.social_icons {
    width:150px;
    height:45px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
.twitter a {
    background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-10px -480px;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    float:right;
    margin:10px 7px 10px 0;
}
.facebook a {
    background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-10px -532px;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    float:right;
    margin:10px 7px 10px 0;
}
.twitter a:hover {
    background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:32px;
    background-position:-10px -480px;
    height:32px;
    float:right;
    margin:10px 9px 10px 0;
}
.facebook a:hover {
    background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:32px;
    background-position:-10px -532px;
    height:32px;
    float:right;
    margin:10px 9px 10px 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
    0 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
    0 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
    0 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.black_overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1001;
    -moz-opacity: .8;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6%;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
#tunein {
    float: right;
    margin: 3px 0px 0 -1px;
    margin-top:15px !important;
}
#tunein img {
    margin: 3px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#tunein img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.song_titel .current_show, .song_titel .current_song {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FD0E62;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.song_titel .current_show span, .song_titel .current_song span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
</style>


<script>
function show_proto() {
    if ($("#chat").css('display') == 'none') {
        $("#chat").show();
    } else {
        $("#chat").hide();
    }
}
</script>

  <div id="chat" style="z-index:1999999;display:none;">



    <iframe id="chat_frame" src="http://www.muzik.gr/chat/index_mini.php" width="470" height="540" name="chat">

        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>

    </iframe>



  </div>





<div style="z-index: 1000000;" id="chatbtn" onclick="show_proto();">

    <h3>Chatbox</h3>

    </div>  

    <div>

    <style>#contactus{position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;background-color:#000;width:300px;padding:10px;color:white;display:block;z-index:99999;}#contactusbtn{background:#666;width:310px;position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:14;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius-topright:5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;background:#333;cursor:pointer;}#contactusbtn h3{background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:-5px -574.5px;margin:0;font-size:20px;padding-left:40px;line-height:2.2;color:#fff;font-weight:700;}#box{position:relative;width:890px;height:100px;top:130px;z-index:14;margin:0 auto;}#box .right_part{width:810px;height:100px;float:left;}#box .right_part .top{width:790px;height:54px;margin-left:10px;}#box .right_part .bottom{width:810px;height:45px;}#box .right_part{width:80px;height:100px;float:left;}.media_icons{width:190px;height:45px;display:inline-block;float:left;text-align:center;}.song_titel{width:510px;height:45px;display:inline-block;float:left;text-align:center;}.social_icons{width:150px;height:45px;display:inline-block;float:left;text-align:center;margin-top:-40px;}.twitter a{background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:-10px -480px;width:32px;height:32px;float:left;margin:10px 7px 10px 0;}.facebook a{background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:-10px -532px;width:32px;height:32px;float:left;margin:10px 7px 10px 0;}.twitter a:hover{background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;width:32px;background-position:-10px -480px;height:32px;float:left;margin:10px 9px 10px 0;}.facebook a:hover{background-image:url(http://www.muzik.gr/wp-content/themes/theme18309/images/spriteme1.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;width:32px;background-position:-10px -532px;height:32px;float:left;margin:10px 9px 10px 0;}@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION1{0%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}@-moz-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION1{0 {

        opacity: 0;

    }

    100% {

        opacity: 1;

    }

    }

    @-o-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION1 {

    0 {

        opacity: 0;

    }

    100% {

        opacity: 1;

    }

    }

    @keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION1 {

    0 {

        opacity: 0;

    }

    100% {

        opacity: 1;

    }

    }

    .black_overlay {

    display: none;

    position: absolute;

    top: 0;

    left: 0;

    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;

    background-color: black;

    z-index: 1001;

    -moz-opacity: .8;

    opacity: .80;

    filter: alpha(opacity=80);

    }

    .white_content {

    display: none;

    position: absolute;

    bottom: 6%;

    left: 0;

    padding: 1px;

    border: 1px solid black;

    background-color: white;

    z-index: 1002;

    overflow: auto;

    }

    #tunein {

    float: left;

    margin: 3px 0px 0 -1px;

    margin-top:15px !important;

    }

    #tunein img {

    margin: 3px;

    opacity: 0.8;

    }

    #tunein img:hover{

    opacity: 1;

    }

  .song_titel .current_show, .song_titel .current_song  {

  font-size: 15px;

  color: #FD0E62;

  font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;

  font-weight: bold;

  height: 20px;

  line-height: 20px;

  }

    .song_titel .current_show span, .song_titel .current_song span  {

  font-size: 12px;

  color: white;

  line-height: 22px;

  font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;

 font-weight: normal;

  }

</style>



<script>

    function show_proto() {

        if ($("#contactus").css('display') == 'none') {

            $("#contactus").show();

        }

        else

        {

            $("#contactus").hide();

        }

    }

</script>

  <div id="contactus" style="z-index:1000000;display:none;">


    <iframe id="contactus_frame" src="http://www.muzik.gr/contactus/contactus.php" width="290" height="600" name="contactus">

        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>

    </iframe>



  </div>





<div style="z-index: 1000000;" id="contactusbtn" onclick="show_proto();">

    <h3>Contact Us</h3>

    </div>  
</div>
```

`
The Chat box button was working before i added the contact us button. after i added the contact us button it brings the contact us button frame

Comment: Could you do a little more work on your code snippet? All the extra spaces are making it quite hard to read. Also, are all those styles required to reproduce your issue? If not, I would suggest removing them to make it more clear. For more info please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Both button click, call the same js function `show_proto()` and it is declare in two times. Change any of the function name, it works. eg: `show_proto1()` and `<div style="z-index: 1000000;" id="chatbtn" onclick="show_proto`();">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for a comment from @TamilSelvan! i could solve my problem! 
The problem was that both of the buttons are calling the same js function! `show_proto()`
So what i did is changed the second function to `show_proto1()` and it solved my problem!